# Mocha test runner (grunt-mocha-test) require timing issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using the `grunt-mocha-test` package to run my unit tests in Node. Here's how the config object for `grunt-mocha-test` looks in my gruntfile:

```
mochaTest: {
  src: watchFiles.serverTests,
  options: {
    reporter: 'spec',
    require: 'server.js'
  }
}
```

`watchFiles.serverTests` is an array of file paths. `server.js` bootstraps my app. In `server.js`, I have something like the following:

```
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
  // Setup express, etc. here
  // Set module exports
});
```

Previously, that looked something like this:

```
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
// Setup express, etc. here (some of which reference db)
// Set module exports
```

The problem was that Express needed the database connection to be successfully in order for it to initialize properly. Without the async database connection, I was getting some strange errors. So, I switched to the async setup. Now, however, when I require `server.js` with the async calls inside, the test runner fires off the Mocha tests before the app is completely fired up. Because of this, I need to find a happy medium along these lines:

```
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
  // Setup express, etc. here
  // Set module exports
});

// Do something here that waits for the above to complete,
// so that the module is loaded synchronously.
```

As an alternative, I can pass a function to the `mochaTest` config object. Is there a way I could create this behavior there?

Comment: you can't "wait" on any asynchronous method in javascript, you must instead use a callback or event.

Comment: I get that, @KevinB. Doesn't do much to help my issue, though...

Comment: The issue is you are trying to do something that is impossible. In other words, you  need to go in another direction. The asynchronous action has a callback, use it.

Comment: How terribly helpful!

Seriously though, I get that it has a callback, and I *am* using it. It doesn't address the issue I'm having. Perhaps my question is poorly titled. The problem isn't so much how to wait on asynchronous activity as it is using asynchronous calls and their callbacks in a require (which I'm doing) and having the grunt task wait to begin testing.

Comment: Really, when I am simply running the app, everything works as I expect, and I'm using this asynchronous call correctly. If I could reach out from that callback and *then* tell the test runner to kick off, all would be good. I don't see a way to do that, though, and just telling me to use a callback doesn't get me any closer.

Comment: i was primarily talking about this comment *"// so that the module is loaded synchronously."* it isn't possible to make the module load synchronously if it has an asynchronous action. You'll need to execute a function int he callback that tells your test runner that the module is done.

Comment: Again, you're telling me what I already know (and have already said...)

Comment: Give us more information about what you are trying to do so that we can help. All i can do at this poitn is tell you what you already know.

Comment: That's what "asynchronous" part describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `before` Function with the `done`-Callback. This will halt your tests until `done` is called. Inside the `before`-Function you can then listen on mongoose `connected`-Event. Something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

before(function(done){
   mongoose.connection.on('connected', done);
});
```

Then just place this before your first test.

Comment: Finally, an actual suggestion! I do appreciate it.

Comment: Did you get this to work? The before call is never firing for me. I have a similar setup where I need JSDOM to finish loading my app's JS file before tests can be run. Does `before()` work outside of the scope of a `describe()`?

Comment: No, it needs to be inside i think.